# Multiple tokens in sign-in using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to create a login page using this sign in method

`Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: customToken ?? "") { (user, error) in
  // ...
}`

Can we have multiple token parameters (registeration ID & Password) for this function ? if yes then how?
[Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth)

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [ask] and [mcve] and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

No, You can not create multiple tokens using single sign-in with firebase.

You have

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: "", completion: { (user, error) in

                })
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "", password: "", completion: { (user, error) in

                })
```